# Unable to debug JavaScript in VS 2012 and IE9 after rollback from IE10

Tags: javascript, debugging, visual-studio-2012, internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-10

I recently accidentally let Windows Update install IE10 on my Windows 7 64bit machine and then uninstalled that update (need IE9 for main dev process). Ever since then I cannot debug JavaScript in VS - getting all too familiar

> Breakpoint will not be hit no symbols have been loaded for this
>   document

Debugging worked flawlessly before update/rollback. Any idea what could've changed and how to change it back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by repairing VS 2012 install. Guess IE10 left some artifacts after being gone.