# Could not debug javascript in visual studio 2013 when IE auto update to 11 from 10

Tags: javascript, .net, internet-explorer, visual-studio-2013

Yesterday the IE auto updated, I make a javascript breakpoint it can't trigger any more.
Now I can't debug it, so sad.
It works well before.
If any method can repair it?

Comment: Did you verify the Disable Script Debugging checkbox is not cleared in the Advanced Settings property page?

Comment: Try running a Repair on Visual Studio install. Helped me on similar (not the same) issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19306989/unable-to-debug-javascript-in-vs-2012-and-ie9-after-rollback-from-ie10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the exact same problem and also thought it was due to IE 11.

After doing lot of research, and not having any success, I looked at the script that were attached to the process when running my code from VS to realise that my script where minified.

After seeing that, I looked at my BundleConfig and saw that configured to explicitly use the minified version of my script.

Instead, I should have used the "*" and let Visual Studio determine if it should bundle the minified or the debug version. I did that when trying to understand how the bundling was working and forgot about the change.

I was using

```
bundles.Add(New ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bSoftOptimax").Include(
    "~/Scripts/bSoft/bSoftOptimax.min.js"
    ))
```

Instead of

```
bundles.Add(New ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bSoftOptimax").Include(
    "~/Scripts/bSoft/bSoftOptimax*"
    ))
```

I think by using "*" you tell VS to create the proper bundle depending if you are debugging or creating an release version of you code.

Once I change the code, everything was working great again.